# Using 'az functionapp createpreviewapp' results in python eror

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli

Per the [Azure Functions on Linux Preview](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Azure-Functions-on-Linux-Preview) page, I am trying to create a new python preview app using:

```
az functionapp createpreviewapp -n MyApp -g MyResourceGroup -l "eastus" -s mystoragename --runtime python --is-linux
```

This is resulting in the following error:

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.46/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 197, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.46/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 369, in execute
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.46/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.46/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    result = cmd(params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.46/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 182, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.46/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 437, in default_command_handler
    result = op(**command_args)
  File "/Users/mike.mahoney/.azure/cliextensions/functionapp/azext_functionapp/custom.py", line 82, in create_function
    site_config.app_settings.append(NameValuePair('FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION', '~2'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I am on a Mac and installed the latest Azure CLI tools (2.0.46) using brew.

Comment: Have you enabled the Azure Functions Linux Consumption preview for your Azure subscription?

Comment: Joy Wang, do you mean by emailing Microsoft? If so, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with the `functionapp` preview extension and the latest update to the az cli.

We updated the instructions here (https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Azure-Functions-on-Linux-Preview#prerequisites) with the latest extension `0.0.2`

You can check the one you have installed by doing

```
az extension list
```

You should see something like

```
[
  {
    "extensionType": "whl",
    "name": "functionapp",
    "version": "0.0.1"
  }
]
```

**To update it:**

Download the `0.0.2` extension wheel from [here](https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/docs/functionapp-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl)

then do

```
az extension remove -n functionapp
az extension add --source <path to the Azure CLI extension whl file saved locally>
```

Comment: After install the 0.0.2 extension, I got another error information `Requested features are not allowed for subscription`, would you mind giving some advice?

Comment: yes, the first thing here (https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Azure-Functions-on-Linux-Preview#access-the-azure-functions-linux-consumption-preview) should be instructions on how to get your subscription white listed for the preview.